# Cannot find fragment by tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some fragments, named `frag1` till `frag12`. They're made/called by order. So, after `frag1` replaced by `frag2`, `frag2` replaced by `frag3`, so on. At `frag10`, I need to go back to `frag2`. But I always got `null` when I tried to access `Frag2` by its `tag`.

First, when moving from `frag1` to `frag2`, I did it like this

```
FragmentTransaction transaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
transaction.replace(((FrameLayout) container).getId(), 
                        new Frag2(getActivity(), container), 
                        "frag2");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Then, at `frag10`, I tried this

```
Fragment frag2 = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag2");
```

and the result was, `frag2` was `null`.

What might have happened? Where's `Frag2`?

Comment: Are you not using the support library on purpose?

Comment: problem is that child fragment manager is somthing different that fragment manager from activity ...

Comment: For library, other fragment transition were successfull, so I don't think it's the problem? I've also tried `getChildFragmentManager()`, still `null`. Hmmm is `Frag2` destroyed when the app reached `Frag10`...?

Comment: @selvin Dayum right that's the problem. I changed here and there that I read wrong place, thought you referred to `Frag1`'s code to call `Frag2`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your fragment is add/ replace by `getFragmentManager` so they are in a same `FragmentManager`
But when retrieve `frag2`, you called `getChildFragmentManager` so of course `frag2` is null.
Try this:

```
Fragment frag2 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag2");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

your are missed

```
ft.addToBackStack(tag);
```

Please add tag name befor commit the fragment and try with the same name

Comment: Thank you, I admit before there's `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` in first code paragraph, but after I changed it to `transaction.addToBackStack("frag2");`, still `null`. Question edited.

Answer (score -1):

use fragment.addToBackStack(TAG) before commit

Comment: Thank you, I admit before there's `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` in first code paragraph, but after I changed it to `transaction.addToBackStack("frag2");`, still `null`.  Question edited.